# find out if a string is preceded by another string with certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

how do i check if a string is preceded by another string.

```
'test@test.com, ,root@boot.com'
```

would become:

```
'test@test.com, root@boot.com'
```

EDIT:

I may have to explain the entire situtation..

I split a string with ',' and check if they are valid email addresses.
If so, the text is removed and stored in another div, if not... the text is left.

This is why when there is 2 successful email addresses and 1 that is not, you are left with:

',,test@test,'

so i need to remove commas that do not have anything behind them apart from space, enter or another comma.

Comment: Why don't you `split` on `,`, and only keep non-empty strings?

Comment: What do you mean by "something else"?

Comment: It is not specific to this, that's why... I need to know how. hehe

Comment: Do you really need to keep the whitespace? Wouldn't `test@test.com,root@boot.com` be a better result?

Comment: it's front end display stuff hehe

Answer (score 1):

If by "something else" you mean "anything except whitespace", then you can use

```
result = subject.replace(/(\s|^),/g, "$1");
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you actually want to condensed repeated commas into single commas. In that case, I'd suggest

```
result = subject.replace(/,(?:\s*,)+/g, ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case, I'd just filter/strip white-spaces.

```
var str = 'test@test.com, ,root@boot.com';

str = str.split(',').filter( removeWhiteSpace );

function removeWhiteSpace( sub ) {
    return !!sub.trim();
}
```